# Self-service cancellation from a registered event seems to be broken

Tags: civievent, error

The following error is reproduceable on a fresh install of CiviCRM 5.35.1 on WordPress 5.7. If self-service cancellation is enabled for a simple event, the cancellation or transfer request results in the following error:

CRM_Core_Exception: getFieldValue failed in /home/bbcadmin2016/sigstage57.net/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/SelfSvcUpdate.php on line 132

The stack trace indicates this:

CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Event_DAO_Ev…', null, 'title') /home/bbcadmin2016/sigstage57.net/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/SelfSvcUpdate.php:132

I am reporting this again in the hope that it can be verified by someone else as a bug  - something that the core team requests before submitting the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try reproducing on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ (I did try and wasn't able to).

Looks like its a environment issue. Could you please check your htaccess or server config? Or WP permlinks?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the culprit was ModSecurity